# Transfer full ownership of calendar in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

Is it possible to transfer full ownership of a calendar in Outlook 2010?

It seems that simply setting a user to the "owner" permission level (via the calendar's properties window) does not grant that user permission to add additional owners, which is what I need to do.

EDIT: Something I forgot to mention is that the users all are on the same Exchange system.

Comment: **Transferring ownership** sounds a bit misleading

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - How so?

Comment: Calendars exist the original owner's account.  You will have to move the actual calendar Object to the account of the new owner that you want fully in charge of it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I suspect that I am misunderstanding you. Do you mean that calendar objects must be physically transferred to the new owner's calendar directory, or that the account recorded in the calendar object's data must be changed? It sounds like you mean the former, but that brings me to wonder what the point of the "owner" permission level is.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Sorry if this reply is redundant; I mistyped your name in my last reply and then corrected it in an edit, but since I don't know if edited in names create notifications I thought it best to make a second reply just in case.

Comment: @Invictus **Transferring Ownership** gives an idea that you are trying to disown that calendar by giving its ownership to someone else. We share or delegate in Outlook. What did you do & exactly how ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - Ah, I see what you mean. That is part of what I am trying to be able to do, I suppose. Specifically, I want to give someone the same rights over the calendar as the original owner, including the addition of more owners - the "owner" permission level does not appear to do this. This would be used if the original owner leaves, so that the calendar can still be used without having to recreate it. This ideally would be done without "demoting" the original owner (so that action can be taken ahead of time), but if need be that might work. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Invictus is it over Exchange ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - Yes, it is. I should add that to the question.

Comment: @Invictus are you trying to share your own calendar or is there a shared calendar and you are trying to add owners to it ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - It's both. I can do the former, but like I said above I cannot do it in a way that allows the latter.